# How to encode video to profile high using ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg, mp4

This is my first post here. I am in a situation where my original file is of profile High and transcoding profile is High10. I am suspecting that this is the cause my video is not getting played in jwplayer. I have also tried to set profile to `-profile:v high`
but no help . I am using ffmpeg version

ffmpeg version 2.6.2

```
No pixel format specified, yuv420p10le for H.264 encoding chosen.
Use -pix_fmt yuv420p for compatibility with outdated media players.
x264 [error]: high profile doesn't support a bit depth of 10
[libx264 @ 0x350d960] Error setting profile high.
[libx264 @ 0x350d960] Possible profiles: baseline main high high10 high422 high444
```

Please help me.

Comment: Like the error message says, use "-pix_fmt yuv420p" and place it after "-profile:v high"

Comment: Tried but ended in _italic_ Incompatible pixel format 'yuv420p' for codec 'libx264', auto-selecting format 'yuv420p10le'
x264 [error]: high profile doesn't support a bit depth of 10
[libx264 @ 0x3acb980] Error setting profile high.
[libx264 @ 0x3acb980] Possible profiles: baseline main high high10 high422 high444

Comment: maybe I need to compile and install ffmpeg than using a build. libx264 seems to be a problem, maybe does not have required codec

Comment: Can you post the entire command you used? And also the output of "ffprobe -i <yourinputfile>"

Comment: Here is the shortest command I am using to check if my "High" video is getting converted to "High" again ----- ffmpeg -i 50_Cent___My_Life_ft__Eminem__Adam_Levine_hd720.mp4 -profile:v high -pix_fmt yuv420p  arvind34.mp4 . The original video downloaded from youtube is of "High " profile which after above command is converted to "High10". ffprobe gives segmentation fault on the input video

Comment: Try ffmpeg -i 50_Cent...mp4 -c:v libx264 -crf 23 -profile:v high -pix_fmt yuv420p -c:a copy arvind34.mp4 2> log.txt      ---   and paste log.txt here

Comment: here it is, short link to this http://pastebin.com/p9y5qqEu

Comment: Ok. Run "ffmpeg -h encoder=libx264 > x264.txt" and paste the line from that textfile starting with 'Supported pixel formats'

Comment: here  it is > http://pastebin.com/hQrPZMKZ

Comment: There you go. the ffmpeg build you have uses libx264 compiled for 10-bit. Apparently one can only build with support for either 8-bit OR 10-bit. So, you'll need a build where libx264 supports 8-bit. Now, the archive that you downloaded includes separate ffmpeg builds for both 8-bit and 10-bit. Can you confirm if you aren't actually running the 10-bit version. And if the build compiler has made a mistake, just download the latest iteration.

Comment: Yes that is what initially suspected. Thanks for making this discussion so far. I compiled ffmpeg from source and it seems to be solving my problem.Please post your last comment as an answer so that I can mark and close it. Thanks!

Comment: Answer posted. Glad it worked out.

Comment: Just a FWIW - In the OP's first comment (above), mention is made of a `Incompatible pixel format 'yuv420p' for codec 'libx264', auto-selecting format 'yuv420p10le' ` error being thrown.  This can most likely be obviated by using `yuv420p10le` as the option for the `-pix_fmt` option, vice `yuv420p`.  IHTH someone!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ffmpeg build you have uses libx264 compiled for 10-bit. Apparently one can only build with support for either 8-bit OR 10-bit. So, you'll need a build where libx264 supports 8-bit.